# foursquare like https

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, foursquare

Want to insert [Like a place button](https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/likebutton) into my website. Everything ok, but it us secured via https, so i Trying to reach https://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js via https, but getting the
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZFWF.png

> You attempted to reach platform.foursquare.com, but instead you
>   actually reached a server identifying itself as a248.e.akamai.net.
>   This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something
>   more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you
>   to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of
>   platform.foursquare.com.

Answer (score 2):

for secure connection we use cdn script adress:
https://platform-s.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js
this adress has right certeficate